Movie with soldiers, a robot and a monster in the jungle
This is an English movie which I watched about 8 years ago. This film is similar to "Predator". 
In it, some soldiers are sent to a jungle. They carry a radar, on which they see two extraordinary creatures. Each of the soldiers are killed, one by one. They think that a robot was killing them but there is actually a giant blood-sucking creature was killing them.
At last one boy and a girl bomb the entire building in the forest are able to escape by a helicopter....
There were some villain soldiers too...

Sounds enticing!

yeah. but the title is unknown...

At the risk of sounding annoying, it's not Predator 2 or "Predators", is it?

So is it from the 00s? 90s? 80? Do you remember where you saw it (DVD, TV, theater)? Anything else, however minor?

hi walt, I saw it from DVD / VCD... If you want I can give more detail about the film..

Sounds a bit like a mockbuster that tried cashing in on any of the newer Predator releases?

its very similar to Predators...

Just letting you know I removed the request for a link to the movie and a list of all possible movies, as they are both off-topic on the site.

That could be a big help for me. But its okay

The ending of DNA (1997) is a bit similar, but some things don't fit. Please clear this up for me: Does the movie have both a monster AND a robot? Or do you mean that the creature only looks like a robot but then turns out to be a monster?

Hi Walt, The movie has both monster and a robot. The first think that tha robot was killing their friends but a creature or monster was killing them. Later they found that Robot was not villain.

Hi Walt, The movie has both monster and a robot. They first think that the robot was killing their friends but a creature or monster was killing them. Robot was actually a wired human-like creature. He takes off his mask later and they found that Robot was not villain. The Robot could Jump very high and long.... –

plz help anyone !!!!!!!!

OK, this might be Code Red (The Rubicon Conspiracy) from 2001:

A psychologically disturbed soldier is forced to come out of retirement to find his brother who has disappeared in the jungle but nothing can prepare him for the alien nightmare he is plunged into.

The soldiers there are picked off (and mutilated) one by one in the jungle and there's a Predator-like android stalking them - but it turns out he's a good alien in a mechanical suit hunting the alien monsters that are killing them (here he is helping the soldiers out). It stars Brian McNamara and Marjean Holden. Here's the cover art:


Thank you so much Walt. I knew just "CODE RED" and when I searched it in youtube without the slogan, it showed no result... I forgot the slogan "The Rubicon Conspiracy".
Thanks For The Support... :)

Can you provide link of the movie in english dubbed or subbed??

Sorry. I couldn't even find clips. This movie is pretty rare.

I found this movie here http://filmix.net/dramy/74255-tayna-rubikona-code-red-the-rubicon-conspiracy-2001.html
But it is in Russian Dubbed...
